# How double can store 1024 bits in just 8 bytes in C++?

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

I can't figure what's going on here.

I find size of following data types in bytes:

```
char:1
int:4
float:4
double:8
long long int:8

Now long long int max size is 9223372036854775807
whereas double max size is 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
```

What!!!

How Mr. double is storing such a large value in just 8 bytes ???

Comment: You should read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: The key here is that floats/doubles dont store their information the same way integral types do. That being said, read the link @sharth posted.

Comment: Mr. double can even store values like `0.5`! :D

Answer (score 5):

> How many decimal digits do I need to represent every integer between 0 and 10<sup>100</sup> - 1?

The answer should be obvious: 100 digits.

> How many decimal digits do I need to represent integral values between 0 and 10<sup>100</sup> - 1, if I only need 7 significant digits?

You only need 9. Every number can be represented as ABCDEFG * 10<sup>HI</sup>.

`double`s work in roughly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation of double max as an integral number (!) looks like this:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It has *lots* of zeros at the end (1024 zeros, to be precise). And before those 1024 zeros are 53 leading ones. Why 53 ones? Because that is the number of **significant bits** you can store in a `double`.

The important part is that all those zeros aren't actually stored inside the double. They are implied by the exponent. Just the 53 ones are stored (well, only 52 ones; the first one is also implied by the format).

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit on the magnitude is determined by a combination of the *significand*, which determines the precision of the number and it's *exponent*, which determines the size. The representation is similar to scientific (n*(10**m)) notation except that it's in base 2.

Many, many base 10 integers and fractions are not representable in the IEEE FP notation which is and always has been a recurring source of problems for new developers.